# Augmented Reality App force closing

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I created a simple app based on the Augmented Reality Concept. 
This is the following java code.

```
package com.kddi.satch.tutorialactivity;                                        

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.kddi.satch.ARViewer;
import com.kddi.satch.LoadScenarioStatus;

public abstract class TutorialActivity_simple extends Activity                                      
{                                       
protected abstract String getSampleScenarioName();                                  
protected abstract String getSampleLogTag();                                    

protected boolean _isInitializedCorrectly;                                  
protected ARViewer _kddiComponent;                                  
protected FrameLayout _frameLayout;                                 

private static final int DIALOG_EXIT = 0;                                   

private void resetMembers()                                 
 {                                  
        _isInitializedCorrectly = false;                                
        _frameLayout = null;                                
        _kddiComponent = null;                              
 }                                  

public void initComponent()                                 
{                                   

        _isInitializedCorrectly = false;                                

        _kddiComponent = new ARViewer(this);                                

        // This FrameLayout must be empty (but initialized) when you pass it to the kddiComponent.initialize() method.                              
        _frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);                               
        _kddiComponent.initialize(_frameLayout);                                


        _isInitializedCorrectly = true;                             
}                                   

@Override                                  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                             

        // Add null to AR Viewer Library compornent's reference.                                
        resetMembers();                             
}                                   

@Override                                  
 public void onRestart() {                                  
        super.onRestart();                              
 }                                  

 @Override                                 
public void onStart() {                                 
    super.onStart();                                
    // Create AR Viewer Library compornent.                             

    initComponent();                                

        postInitComponent();                                

    initContentView();                              

    if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              
                // Do authorize and madia is loaded.                            
                // You must call loadScenario() method.                         
                loadScenario();                         
    }                               
 }                                  

@Override                                  
public void onResume(){                                 
        super.onResume();                               

        if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              
            // GL context is recreated and media is reloaded.                           
            _kddiComponent.onResume();                          
            reservePlayScenario();                          
        }                               
}                                   

 @Override                                 
public void onPause() {                                 
        // When the activity is paused the GL context is destroyed, so all media is unloaded.                               
        if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              
            cancelReservePlayScenario();                            
            if (_kddiComponent.checkLoadScenarioStatus() == LoadScenarioStatus.COMPLETE) {                          
                _kddiComponent.pauseScenario();                         
            }                           
            _kddiComponent.onPause();                           
        }                               

        super.onPause();                                
}                                   

@Override                                  
public void onStop() {                                  
        releaseContentView();                               

        // Destroy AR Viewer Library Objects.                               
        if (_isInitializedCorrectly)                                
        {                               
            _kddiComponent.terminate();                         
            _kddiComponent = null;                          
            _frameLayout = null;                            
        }                               

        super.onStop();                             
}                                   

@Override                                  
public void onDestroy() {                                   
        // Destroy AR Viewer Library Objects.                               
        if (_isInitializedCorrectly)                                
        {                               
            _frameLayout = null;                            
            _kddiComponent = null;                          
        }                               

        super.onDestroy();                              

        resetMembers(); // forced clean                             
}                                   

@Override                                  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)                                 
{                                   
        switch(keyCode){                                
                case android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :                           
                showDialog( DIALOG_EXIT );                          
                return true;                            
    }                               
        return false;                               
}                                       

public void postInitComponent()                                 
{                                   
        // override this if you need to do some special handling on the component after standard initialization                             

        if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              
            _kddiComponent.activateAutoFocusOnDownEvent(true);                          
        }                               
}                                   

public void initContentView()                                   
{                                   
        // override this if you need to do some special handling on the component after standard initialization                             

        if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              

            // you'll probably use some other UI object as the content view that itself will embed the component's frame layout -- here you can change all this                         

            // by default, the frame layout containing DFusion will be the activity content view                            
            setContentView(_frameLayout);                           
        }                               
}                                   

public void releaseContentView()                                    
{                                   
        // override this if you need to do some special handling on the component after standard initialization                             

        if (_isInitializedCorrectly) {                              
            // do here the release of the your UI instances (if customized)                         
        }                               
}                                   

public void loadScenario()                                  
{                                   
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;                             
        PackageManager packMgmr = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();                              
        try {                               
            appInfo = packMgmr.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);                         
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {                             
            e.printStackTrace();                            
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate assets, aborting...");                         
        }                               
        String dpdfile = appInfo.sourceDir + getSampleScenarioName();                               
        _kddiComponent.loadScenario(dpdfile);                               
}                                   

// Set polling rate for loading the media.                                  
private final int REPEAT_INTERVAL = 100;                                    
private Handler handler = new Handler();                                    
private Runnable runnable = null;                                   

private void reservePlayScenario()                                  
{                                   
        if (runnable == null)                               
        {                               
        runnable = new Runnable()                           
         {                          
            @Override                      
            public void run()                       
             {                      
                                LoadScenarioStatus status = _kddiComponent.checkLoadScenarioStatus();                   
                                if (status == LoadScenarioStatus.CANCEL)                    
                                {                   
                                    // cancel(appli suspend)                
                                }                   
                                else if (status == LoadScenarioStatus.COMPLETE)                 
                                {                   
                                    // Ready to play scenario               
                                    _frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);               
                                    _kddiComponent.playScenario();              
                                }                   
                                else if (                   
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_NETWORK_UNUSABLE ||              
                                    // faild to load a media becase of no network connection.               
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_NETWORK ||               
                                    // faild to load a media becase of network error.               
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_SOFTWAREKEY ||               
                                    // faild to load a media becase software key has not be found on server.                
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_CONTENT_STOPPED ||               
                                    // faild to load a media becase content has stopped.                
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_SERVER ||                
                                    // faild to load a media becase of server error.                
                                    status == LoadScenarioStatus.ERROR_ETC              
                                    // faild to load a media becase of another error.               
                                )                   
                                {                   
                                    // error                
                                }                   
                                else                   
                                {                   
                    handler.postDelayed(this, REPEAT_INTERVAL);             
                                }                   
            }                       
        };                          
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, REPEAT_INTERVAL);                         
        }                               
}                                   

private void cancelReservePlayScenario()                                    
{                                   
        if (handler != null && runnable != null)                                
        {                               
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);                          
                runnable = null;                            
        }                               
}                                   

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {                                   
    Dialog dialog;                              
    switch(id) {                                
        case DIALOG_EXIT:                           
        {                           
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                        
                    builder.setMessage(                     
                        "Really want to quit the sample?"                  
                )                       
                .setCancelable(true)                        
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                       
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                   
                                finish();               
                    }})                 
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                        
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                   
                                dialog.cancel();                
                        }});                    
                    dialog = builder.create();                      
                    break;                      
        }                           

        default:                            
        dialog = null;                          
    }                               
    return dialog;                              
}                                   
}                                       
//-- end of file --
```

The manifest.xml file of the app looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" package="com.kddi.satch.tutorial">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:debuggable="false">
<!-- configChanges setting -->
    <activity android:name=".Tutorial"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<!-- define the resolution -->
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true">
</supports-screens>
<!-- permit camera usage if authorized -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- define Autofocus -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Now, Whenever I run the app on the emulator, the app force closes while loading for the first time and the following error occurs.

```
06-06 22:55:00.157: A /libc(19290): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1)
06-06 22:55:00.173: E /ti.dfusionmobile.tiComponent(19290): ON SURFACE CREATED
```

Any guidance on what and where I am going wrong would be appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the augmented reality sdk use the phone GPU to execute opengl command. This is not supported on the emulator so you can only run the application on a phone.

Best

Comment: Agreed. Tested it on my phone and the app was running just fine. Thanks for the reply anyways.